# Unclear behavior by Garbage Collector while collecting instance properties or fields of reachable object

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, .net-core, garbage-collection

Till today I was thinking that members of ***reachable objects*** are also considered to be reachable.

But, today I found one behavior which creates a problem for us either when ***`Optimize Code` is checked*** or application is executed in ***Release Mode***. It is clear that, release mode comes down to the code optimization as well. So, it seems code optimization is reason for this behavior.

Let's take a look to that code:

```
 public class Demo
 {
     public Action myDelWithMethod = null;

     public Demo()
     {
         myDelWithMethod = new Action(Method);

         // ... Pass it to unmanaged library, which will save that delegate and execute during some lifetime 

         // Check whether object is alive or not after GC
         var reference = new WeakReference(myDelWithMethod, false);

         GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
         GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
         GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);

         Console.WriteLine(reference.IsAlive);
         // end - Check whether object is alive or not after GC
     }

     private void Method() { }
 }
```

I simplified code a bit. Actually, we are using our special delegate, not `Action`. But the behavior is same. This code is written in mind with "members of ***reachable objects*** are also considered to be reachable". But, that delegate will be collected by GC asap. And we have to pass it to some unmanaged library, which will use it for some time.

You can test demo by just adding that line to the `Main` method:

```
var p = new Demo();
```

I can understand the reason of that optimization, but what is the recommended way to prevent such case without creating another function which will use that variable `myDelWithMethod` which will be called from some place? ***One, option I found that, it will work if I will set `myDelWithMethod` in the constructor like so:***

```
myDelWithMethod = () => { };
```

Then, it won't be collected until owning instance is collected. It seems it can't optimize code in the same way, if lambda expression is setted as a value.

So, will be happy to hear your thoughts. Here are my questions:

- ***Is it right that, members of reachable objects are also considered to
  be reachable***?
- ***Why it is not collected in case of lambda expression?***
- ***Any recommended ways to  prevent collection in such cases?***

Comment: I don't see anything unusual in your example. you don't have anything that refers to `myDelWithMethod` passed g. collection. Hence, object collected. May be I don't understand something?

Comment: @T.S. What do you think of my first sentence? ` members of reachable objects are also considered to be reachable`. Also, why it is not collected in case of lambda expression? And any recommended ways to  prevent collection in such cases?

Comment: [Recommended read](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=13193). And [`GC.KeepAlive(…)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=netframework-4.8). Further, I’m sure, C# allows sharing/reusing of the object associated with the lambda expression, which is not a sign of absence of optimization, but just a different kind of optimization.

Comment: @Holger Regarding to `Gc.KeepAlive`. It won't affect anything if I will call it inside ctor. For example I can put it inside `Dispose` and make that class ti implement `IDisposable`. What do you think of my first two questions?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference id the containing class is reachable. Your private member is a weak reference and once constructor is executed, it is gone

Comment: @T.S. my private member is `Action`, not `WeakReference`

Comment: `Regarding to Gc.KeepAlive. It won't affect anything` - are you calling it *after* the last `GC.Collect` like you should? Also please see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100813-00/?p=13153 in addition to already mentioned https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=13193.

Comment: I don’t know the specification of C#, as I’m working with Java, so while there are a lot of similarities, there can be subtle differences. In Java, it’s indeed guaranteed that objects reachable through the member variable are reachable too, however, just like with C#, the execution of an instance method does not necessarily make `this` reachable, neither the member referenced objects. The completion of the constructor has a special semantic, but only to the finalizer of the same object. In the absence of it, there is no ordering constraint, so you’d still need `GC.KeepAlive(myDelWithMethod)`.

Comment: I agree with @Holger, even inside an instance method an object may become unreachable (thus, also `this` and your delegate).

Comment: @Holger Inside ctor KeepAlive doesnt make sense as this delegate will be executed from unmanaged code.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, are you sure that the answer to my 1st question is No?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev the answer is Yes, members of reachable objects are also considered to be reachable. But the problem is different in your case, you `Demo` object becomes unreachable already during its constructor execution.

Comment: *"my private member is `Action`, not `WeakReference`"*... And then this in constructor `new WeakReference(myDelWithMethod, false)`. You marked your action as weak reference, so, it is removed once there is no further usage. If you would pass reference to your action somewhere, like add this to the list in some other class, it will not be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However strange this would sound, JIT is able to treat an object as unreachable even if the object's instance method is being executed - including constructors.

An example would be the following code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SomeClass sc = new SomeClass() { Field = new Random().Next() };
   sc.DoSomethingElse();
}
class SomeClass
{
   public int Field;
   public void DoSomethingElse()
   {
      Console.WriteLine(this.Field.ToString());
      // LINE 2: further code, possibly triggering GC
      Console.WriteLine("Am I dead?");
   }
   ~SomeClass()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Killing...");
   }
}
```

that  may print:

```
615323
Killing...
Am I dead?
```

This is because of ***inlining*** and ***Eager Root Collection technique*** - `DoSomethingElse` method do not use any `SomeClass` fields, so `SomeClass` instance is no longer needed after `LINE 2`.

This happens to code in your constructor. After `// ... Pass it to unmanaged library` line your `Demo` instance becomes unreachable, thus its field `myDelWithMethod`. This answers the first question.

The case of empty lamba expression is different because in such case this lambda is cached in a static field, always reachable:

```cs
public class Demo
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();
        public static Action <>9__1_0;
        internal void <.ctor>b__1_0()
        {
        }
    }

    public Action myDelWithMethod;
    public Demo()
    {
        myDelWithMethod = (<>c.<>9__1_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__1_0 = new Action(<>c.<>9.<.ctor>b__1_0)));
    }
}
```

Regarding recommended ways in such scenarios, you need to make sure `Demo` has lifetime long enough to cover all unmanaged code execution. This really depends on your code architecture. You may make `Demo` static, or use it in a controlled scope related to the unmanaged code scope. It really depends.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I am satisfied with the information which is given in your answer. And, unfortunately this library is 3rd party library, which is started to fail in that case. So, we cant change ot much. It seems I can continue to use lambda or define that delegate statically. By, the way another weird thing is that, that delegate inside Demo is collected in both framework and core. But, real app fails with that reason only in core. May be it is due to GC and optimization difference between framework and core. What do you think of that?

Comment: For sure Eager Root Collection is a deep implementation detail and may vary between runtimes, so I would say it is even expected that there will be some differences. Keep in mind also that .NET Core has now Tired JIT so differences may occur even inside the same runtime but at various points in time, depending on which JIT was used - AFAIK QuickJIT is not using (or using not very aggressive) root collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I always find it a bit hard to get some up-to-date info about GC.