# GC Eager Root Collection

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

On pg 96 of *Pro .NET Performance - Optimize Your C# Applications* it talks about GC eager root collection:

> For each local variable, the JIT embeds into a table the addresses of
>   the earliest and latest instruction pointers where the variable is
>   still relevant as a root. The GC then uses these tables when it
>   performs its stack walk.

It then provides this example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Widget a = new Widget();
        a.Use();
        //...additional code
        Widget b = new Widget();
        b.Use();
        //...additional code
        Foo(); //static method
    }
```

It then says:

> The above discussion implies that breaking your code into smaller
>   methods and using fewer local variables is not just a good design
>   measure or a software engineering technique. With the .NET GC, it can
>   provide a performance benefit as well because you have fewer local
>   roots! It means less work for the JIT when compiling the method, less
>   space to be occupied by the root IP tables, and less work for the GC
>   when performing its stack walk.

I don't understand how breaking code into smaller methods would help.
I've broken the code up into this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UseWidgetA();
        //...additional code
        UseWidgetB();
        //...additional code
        Foo(); //static method
    }

    static void UseWidgetA()
    {
        Widget a = new Widget();
        a.Use();
    }

    static void UseWidgetB()
    {
        Widget b = new Widget();
        b.Use();
    }
}
```

**Fewer local roots:**

Why are there fewer local roots?
There are still the same number of local roots, one local root in each method.

**Less work for the JIT when compiling the method:**

Surely this would make things worse because it would need 2 extra tables for the 2 extra methods. The JIT would also still need to record the earliest and latest instruction pointers where the variable is still relevant within each method, but it would just have more methods to do that for.

**Less work for the GC when performing its stack walk:**

How does having more smaller methods mean less work for the GC during the stack walk?

Comment: That's rather esoteric optimizing. Generally, small methods are not bad, however, the reason why you can split this example code this way is that you are not using the variables in the next steps, so you can limit their scope to the smaller methods. You could achieve a similar effect by using curly braces within one method, but generally, the JIT is smart enough to recognize unused variables and omitting them from the GC roots. See [this Q&A from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59361295/2711488) discussing exactly that. So just for GC performance, you don't need to split the method.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not in Sasha's mind but let me put my two cents to that.

First of all, I perceive it as a generalized rule - when you split a method into smaller ones, there is a chance that some parts will not need to be JITted, because some subroutines are executed conditionally.

Secondly, JITting indeed produces so-called *GC info* about live stack roots. The bigger method, the bigger *GC info* is Theoretically, there should be also a bigger cost of interpreting it during the GC, however, this is overcome by splitting GC Info into chunks. However, information about the stack roots liveness is stored only for so-called *safe points*. There are two types of methods:

- *partially interruptible* - the only safe points are during calls to other methods. This makes a method less "suspendable" because the runtime needs to wait for such a safe point to suspend a method, but consumes less memory for the GC info.
- *fully interruptible* - every instruction of a method is treated as a safe point, which obviously makes a method very "suspendable" but requires significant storage (of quantity similar to the code itself)

As Book Of The Runtime says: *“The JIT chooses whether to emit fully- or partially
interruptible code based on heuristics to find the best trade-off between code quality,
size of the GC info, and GC suspension latency.”*

In my opinion, smaller methods help the JIT to make better decisions (based on its heuristics) to make methods partially or fully interruptible.